# Why is the expected type here different from my param? And how do I go about fixing it?

Tags: java, hibernate

//Here is the Interface that the Coffee Repository is linked through
  //as well as pulling from
   //I need help assessing why my code is give me an error that states
        <
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element     [com.theironyard.Entities.Coffee@123ec0f1] did not match expected type     [com.theironyard.Entities.Tag (n/a)]>

```
   package com.theironyard.Repositories;

   import com.theironyard.Entities.Coffee;
   import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
   import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;




    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by darionmoore on 1/26/17.
 */
    public interface CoffeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Coffee, Integer> {
    Coffee findFirstByName(String name);
    Coffee findBySubmitted(LocalDateTime submitted);
    List<Coffee> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String search);
    Page<Coffee> findAll(Pageable pageable);
    Page<Coffee> findByTags(Pageable pageable, List<Coffee> taggedCoffee);

}


//Here is my entire Navigation controller Class with all imports and
//Implementations

    package com.theironyard.Controllers;

    import com.theironyard.Command.RatingCommand;
    import com.theironyard.Entities.Coffee;
    import com.theironyard.Entities.Tag;
    import com.theironyard.Entities.User;
    import com.theironyard.Repositories.*;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by darionmoore on 1/26/17.
 */
    @Controller
    public class NavigationController {
    public static final String CURRENT_USER = "username";

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    CoffeeRepository coffeeRepository;

    @Autowired
    RecentCoffeeRepository recentCoffeeRepository;

    @Autowired
    TagRepository tagRepository;

    @Autowired
    RatingRepository ratingRepository;

    /**
     * Gets the community/home page
     * @param session
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCommunityPage(Model model, HttpSession session){
        List<Coffee> coffee = coffeeRepository.findAll();
        ArrayList <Coffee> recCoffee = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Coffee c : coffee){
            if(c.getSubmitted().isBefore(LocalDateTime.now()) && c.getSubmitted().isAfter(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1))){
                recentCoffeeRepository.save(c);
                recCoffee.add(c);
            }
        }

        model.addAttribute("coffee", coffee);
        model.addAttribute("recent", recCoffee);
        return "community-page";
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current users account page
     * @param session
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(path = "/user-account", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUserAccount(Model model, HttpSession session){
        if(session.getAttribute(CURRENT_USER) == null){
            return "redirect:/user-exception";
        }
        User userId = userRepository.findFirstByUsername((String)session.getAttribute(CURRENT_USER));
        model.addAttribute("preferences", userId.getPreferredCoffee());
        return "user-account";
    }

    /**
     * Not sure about this yet
     * @param session
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(path = "/user-account", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String userAccount(HttpSession session){
        return "user-account";
    }


    /**
     * Gets a specific coffee and its information based on the ID of said coffee
     * @param model
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(path = "/coffee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCoffee(Model model, HttpSession session, int id){
        Coffee coffee = coffeeRepository.findOne(id);
        List tags = tagRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("coffee", coffee);
        model.addAttribute("tags", coffee.getTags());
        model.addAttribute("rates", coffee.getRatings());
        return "coffee";
    }

    /**
     * Just in case method
     * @param session
     * @param ratingCommand
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(path = "/coffee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String Coffee(HttpSession session, RatingCommand ratingCommand, int id){
        Coffee coffeeId = coffeeRepository.findOne(id);
        User userId = userRepository.findOne(id);
        return "redirect:/coffee?id="+ id;
    }

    /**
     * Implement pageination for the coffee list
     * Also adds the Coffee object to the coffee-list
     * @param session
     * @param page
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(path = "/coffee-list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCoffeeList(Model model, HttpSession session, String tag, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page){
        List<Tag> tags = tagRepository.findAll();
        Page<Coffee> coffees;

        if(tag != null){
//            Tag filteredTag = tagRepository.findByDescription(tag);
//            List<Tag> coffeeByTag = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Coffee> filtered = coffeeRepository.findAll();
            List<Coffee> filterByTag = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Coffee c : filtered){
                c.getTags();
                for(Tag t : c.getTags()) {
                    if (t.getDescription().equalsIgnoreCase(tag)){
                        filterByTag.add(c);
                    }
                }
            }
            coffees = coffeeRepository.findByTags(new PageRequest(page, 10), filterByTag);
        }
        else{
            coffees = coffeeRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(page, 10));
        }

        if(coffees.hasPrevious()){
            model.addAttribute("prev", true);
            model.addAttribute("prevPageNum", page - 1);
        }

        if(coffees.hasNext()){
            model.addAttribute("next", true);
            model.addAttribute("nextPageNum", page + 1);
        }

        model.addAttribute("tags", tags);
        model.addAttribute("coffees", coffees);
        return "coffee-list";
    }

    /**
     * Just in case method
     * @param session
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(path = "/coffee-list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String coffeeList(HttpSession session){
        return "coffee-list";
    }

    /**
     * Just in case method
     * @param model
     * @param session
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(path = "/about-us", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAboutUs(Model model, HttpSession session){
        return "about";
    }

    /**
     * Just in case method
     * @param session
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(path = "/about-us", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String AboutUs(HttpSession session){
        return "redirect:/about-us";
    }

}

<I don't know what else to add so I'm adding things arbitrarily to make sure that I can submit this edit>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136695/discussion-on-question-by-darion-moore-why-is-the-expected-type-here-different-f).